# Firestore async call inside useEffect() function causes error when navigating around routes

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, setstate, use-effect

Async function for fetching an image from Firestore Storage causes an error when I navigate to another route and comeback.  Here is the `useEffect` method in Items component

```
const Item = (props) => {
const [itemImage, setItemImage] = useState('')
const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState('')
const [isDeleting, setIsDeleting] = useState(false)

useEffect(()=>{
    setItemImage(placeholder)  
    if(props.itemImage){
        firestoreService.getImageUrl(props.itemImage, 'itemImage')
            .then(url => {
                
                setItemImage(url)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("error")
            })
    }      
},[])
```

The component called Item gets rendered only in `/items` route. When I go back to `/` route and come back to `/items` route, I get the following error. How can I fix it?

[image: Warning: Can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component error]

Comment: Can you please provide some code ? and also your image is not viewable

Comment: The image shows an error: "index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in Item (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Items.js:47)"

Comment: @MohammadFaisal I'll add code in a sec. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to setState on an unMounted Component you get this error message.

Here in your example

```
firestoreService.getImageUrl(props.itemImage, 'itemImage')
            .then(url => {
                setItemImage(url)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("error")
            })
```

you are calling a function that will take some time to return.
meanwhile if you go back to another component/route your current component becomes unmounted but when you get the return from firebase it tries to update the state in
`setItemImage(url)`

thats why you are getting this error.

Comment: Thanks. How can I get around this issue? Is there any way to avoid the setItemImage(url) call if the component is unmounted?

Comment: you can try to separate your api call in separate custom hook. and return url from it. that way your component is no longer dependent on firebase.  it will be cleaner too.